# Linq query, select everything from one lists property that starts with a string in another list

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

Hello I'm new to linq and lambda

I have two lists

```
fl.LocalOpenFiles ...
List<string> f....
```

there is a property (string) for example taking index 0

```
fl.LocalOpenFiles[0].Path
```

i wanted to select all from the first list `fl.LocalOpenFiles` where `fl.LocalOpenFiles.Path` starts with a string from the `List<string> f`

I finally got this...

```
List<LocalOpenFile> lof = new List<LocalOpenFile>();
lof = fl.LocalOpenFiles.Join(
    folders,
    first => first.Path,
    second => second,
    (first, second) => first)
    .ToList();
```

But its just selecting folders that meet the requirement `first.Path == second` and i couldnt find a way to get the data that i want which is something meeting this "braindump" requirement:

```
f[<any>] == fl.LocalOpenFiles[<any>].Path.Substring(0, f[<any>].Length)
```

Another Example...

```
List<string> f = new List<string>{ "abc", "def" };
List<LocalOpenFile> lof = new List<LocalOpenFile>{ 
    new LocalOpenFile("abc"),
    new LocalOpenFile("abcc"),
    new LocalOpenFile("abdd"),
    new LocalOpenFile("defxsldf"),)}

    // Result should be
    // abc
    // abcc
    // defxsldf
```

I hope i explained it in a understandable way :)
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this :

```
List<LocalOpenFile> result = 
        lof.Where(file => f.Any(prefix => file.Path.StartsWith(prefix)))
           .ToList();
```

Comment: +1, Any is definitely more compact, although the variable naming could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular `where` instead of a join, which will give you more straight forward control over the selection criteria;

```cs
var result = 
    from file in lof
    from prefix in f
    where file.Path.StartsWith(prefix)
    select file.Path;   // ...or just file if you want the LocalOpenFile objects
```

Note that a file matching multiple prefixes may show up more than once. If that is a problem, you can just add a call to `Distinct` to eliminate duplicates.

EDIT:
If you - as it seems in this case - only want to know the matching path and not the prefix it matches (ie you only want data from one collection as in this case), I'd go for @har07's `Any` solution instead.